# Send sourcecode from pipeline to another template in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to implement `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack` across my code to avoid to repeat code multiples times.   (in this case, a cloudwatch alert for each lambda)

Previously to this change, I am doing, I had my "alarms.json" into one of the actions on the `AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline` and it worked properly.

But the file becomes a mess as I have 15 alarms that are the same, just changing the names of the lambda names that need to jump on. so for that, I had the idea of creating a file, with a single alarm in there; which receives the lambda name as the parameter.

So here became my doubt, in the `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack` the `TemplateURL` should be an `S3` location, but I may be doing something wrong because the error I am getting says that `TemplateURL must be an Amazon S3 URL.`

so to achieve this, what I am doing is:
on the .json that i have my alarm I added a new parameter

```
"SourceCodeS3": 
{
    "Description": "Sourcecode",
    "Type": "String",
    "ConstraintDescription": "Source code Location in s3"
}
```

and then in the same file, I have a stack as

```
"stackAlarm":
{
    "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
    "Properties" : {
        "Parameters" : {"Name" : {"Ref": "lambda"} },
        "TemplateURL" : {
            "Fn::ImportValue": { "Fn::Sub": "${SourceCodeS3}/AWSAlarms/lambdaAlarm.json" } 
            },
        "TimeoutInMinutes" : 20
        }
}
```

So in the pipeline I have an `action deploy` like the next:

```
{
    "ActionTypeId" : {
        "Category" : "Deploy",
        "Owner" : "AWS",
        "Provider" : "CloudFormation",
        "Version" : "1"
    },
    "Configuration" : {
        "ActionMode": "REPLACE_ON_FAILURE",
        "StackName": "RawDataApplication",
        "Capabilities": "CAPABILITY_IAM,CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM",
        "ChangeSetName": "code-pipeline-update",
        "RoleArn": "arn",
        "TemplatePath": "BuildArtifact::lambdas.json", //This calls properly
        "ParameterOverrides": "{\"Environment\": \"Internal\", \"SourceCodes3\" : \"BuildArtifact::AWS\" }"
    },
    "Name" : "namehere",
    "InputArtifacts" : [{
        "Name": "BuildArtifact"
    }],
    "Region" : {"Ref": "AWS::Region"},
    "RoleArn" : "arn",
    "RunOrder" : 1
}
```

The location of the file is `$AWS/AWSAlarms/lambdaAlarm.json`

This is weird because I am getting two different errors:
1 in the pipeline: `Parameters: [SourceCodeS3] must have values` which make me think that I'm not sending anything 
2 in cloudformation: If I go to the actual error and go to the event I see: `TemplateURL must be an Amazon S3 URL.` which probably is because is empty

In addition to this, I tried in the `buildspec` file to return an artifact which is the file. but it didn't work. 
I also tried to access the file using the `sourceCode` adding it firest to the `InputArtifacts` and then to the `ParameterOverrides`

```
"InputArtifacts" : 
[{
    "Name": "BuildArtifact"
},{
    "Name": "SourceCode"
}]
"ParameterOverrides": "{\"Environment\": \"Internal\", \"SourceCodes3\" : \"BuildArtifact::AWS\" }"
```

and also using the get attr thing

```
"ParameterOverrides": "{\"Environment\": \"Internal\", \"SourceCodes3\" : { \"Fn::GetArtifactAtt\" : [ \"SourceCode\", \"Name\" ] } }"
```

At this point, I am wondering if what I am trying to achieve is possible and if I am doing it in the correct way.

Can someone help me,

Thanks.

Comment: can you tell what this is the resolved url of 
"Fn::ImportValue": { "Fn::Sub": "${SourceCodeS3}/AWSAlarms/lambdaAlarm.json" }"
this code, you can access it from the parameters section of the (child) stack in cloudformation

Comment: *" to avoid to repeat code multiples times. (in this case, a cloudwatch alert for each lambda)"* have you considered using a jinja macro to accomplish this?

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver Hi, No, we want to avoid to use any other tool rather than the ones provided by Amazon.

Comment: @MHamzaRazzaq when it fails, the stack does a rollback and I cannot access to the new parameters/template, when I click on those tabs it shows me the last valid one.

Comment: @TiGreX you can go to the deleted stack and check the parameter value from there.
I am using the same approach as your described in this question and it is working for me, just make sure that your Template URL format should be like this  https:// s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/folder/.../template.json